How to determine P,Q,D in SARIMA model?
I am going to forecast the crude oil export values from 2010 January to December 2023. using the SARIMA model as my series have trend and seasonal components. The m value  is 12. After doing a log transformation and differencing by lags 1 to get rid of the trend, I plotted the ACF and PACF shown in the picture : ACF and PACF
After differencing the log data, I can not determine the P,D,Q parameters to the SARIMA model. How can I determine the parameters using ACF, and PACF correlogram? Is there a way to fix this? Or should this be specified in another way?
Thanks!
Edit: I test the P,D,Q parameters with P = 0, D = 0,1 and Q = 0, even some models like SARIMA (1,1,1)(0,0,0); SARIMA(1,1,1)(1,0,1); SARIMA(1,1,1)(0,1,0); SARIMA(1,1,1)(1,1,1) but the coefficients of the models are not significant, especially AR. And the forecast value is not precious according to the actual value.
genr logvalue = log(tri_gia) 
ls d(logvalue) c ar(1) ma(1) 
ls d(logvalue) c ar(1) ma(1) sma(12) sar(12) 
ls d(logvalue,1,12) ar(1) ma(1) 
ls d(logvalue,1,12) ar(1) ma(1) sma(12)
ls d(logvalue,1,12) c ar(1) ma(1) sma(12) sar(12) 

